# Stuck in Indenting spaces according to numbers using a nested loop

Tags: java, string, loops, nested-loops

I need some help. I want my program to print different numbers according to the user's input and indent that number with that number of spaces as well. Must be using a nested loop.

**Expected Output:**  (lets say user types `3`)

```
0  
 1
  2
   3
```

for simplicity I'm only showing you what I did in the nested for loop and ignoring the user's input portion.

**What I did:**

```
for (i=0; i<=userNum; i++) 
  {
     for (j=0; j<=i; j++) 
     {
        ? (I think here is the problem as I don't know how to indent by that no of spaces)
     }
     System.out.println(i);
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you think should be inside that loop? What is its purpose?

Comment: @Pshemo, its purpose should be to indent with spaces according to the number for each line. I only know `System.out.println();`, but thats something else.

Comment: Hint: Beside `println(data)` there is also `print(data)` method. Difference is that `print(data)` doesn't automatically add line separator after `data`. This allows us to print `data` many times *in same line*.

Comment: @Pshemo, thanks a lot. I knew about this `print(data)`, but I never wonder it would be needed here. All credits to you :) Here is what I put inside nested loop `System.out.print(" "); ` and changed `j = 1`

Comment: Good job and good luck with your next exercises. One advice: get used to iterating from 0 since most things in Java (and in other languages) are indexed from `0` till `max-1` (like arrays). So instead of `for (int i = 1; i<=max; i++)` try to getting used to `for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the loop you should use

```
System.out.print(" ");
```